# How to access class from another project?

Tags: c#, class, project

I have two projects in different solutions,

How can I access classes from one project in the another one?

Comment: Add reference to the project in another project.

Comment: Check this ---> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the present working solution creating a reference to the project you want to access the classes from. IN visual studio which I use you use the 
Reference Manager Dialog box or Add reference Dialog box

Answer (score 0):

Right click your solution, and click on **add>add existing item**. Then select the other solution's class; this will add that class to your present solution. Or just add the other solution into your present solution; this will combine two separate solutions into one place. After that you can add any class reference from your other solution to the present solution.